# How I can parse HTML from Blazor-based website? C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, signalr

## THE PROBLEM

There is a web page with students' schedules: https://education.khai.edu/union/schedule/.

When I make a request by the link I get "empty" HTML. It means that responded HTML contains JS-scripts only, no schedule HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-UA">
<head>

    ...

    <!--Blazor:{"sequence":1,"type":"server","descriptor":"CfDJ8MBhIHG65FtKlX56pWtbUtQZ6T285HAgOYeCRtbbe9JO4U4cZsYQJ9xvkrUrO01rnP\u002BgDnPMCl0MnI0E/fW58mYoqDZ3J1ztRz/DKm9\u002BABDrmL5ArBFfTFdeO82HHavNnd1E10j7gHBU9uqKmOW2otP1y5s/a\u002BnMT/P2jvdetcCcDQvdfLnX2/w747D4dYNA1MuoeBRlst63xJlks\u002BYeAfhhNMi1s961JEi777JANAEi\u002B9g\u002BNf7aS9sLn\u002BbJZ4m0IBrUnCcHbu3idntWrD/GDpgDVCwhrIhUIPhs8ITgqZHJdQprUnffKWflcMbJ6YyyWBBABTi2eOX/VMHvtFWxT8ABDgmXbyqC3vTfRe6VlwN5ibDYH/UKDkULoJuX\u002Bw\u002BQB2e3sSP1OddN/ud8pWe5\u002BuCo3\u002BkQ9OG6x2GLMXJHWgah"}-->
</head>
<body class="x-background">

<!--Blazor:{"sequence":0,"type":"server","descriptor":"CfDJ8MBhIHG65FtKlX56pWtbUtTdcyRUeUr\u002BhT344Mo3B4Gc0Gg3YwX1FY0c9owxv7oR1MDnLFR1BTJFjhuwYAjnROc3JT8UhSCkRbOdLVMuG0iwpNvwHNc47\u002BrguaHCTkDZKvZ9GKc0Jp\u002BCX0hcssqhCnp6eka\u002BG9Q7XF2B4ARhWnuJDKvUT\u002BbuWra063kFqG0Ixs4eWc4KrPRNS1KnTVu3QZrmx8r9dx6iyQXHjN/YgTqJhcv9LoQqWTfncbhBLwGm9l0BCTBLn3fGdJsOB6ES0lRwvVygmY7DA/2OGzhY7jGppr6UNaUXhdgo4xZDi3FkZgY3OL5xGS1p0bkc14UU9TM="}-->
    <script async src="/ui/app.js?v=3hNtGnhO8Vl6rh70OirKX4BnS6mxiiS5k9p3XAvofZA"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false"></script>
    <script src="_content/Blazor-Analytics/blazor-analytics.js"></script>
    <script>
    async function connectionDown() {
        console.log("Blazor disconnected");
        location.reload();
    }

    function connectionUp() {
        console.log("Blazor connected");
    }

    window.Blazor.start({
        reconnectionOptions: {
            maxRetries: 10,
            retryIntervalMilliseconds: 500,
        },
        reconnectionHandler: {
            onConnectionDown: e => connectionDown(e),
            onConnectionUp: e => connectionUp(e)
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the web page from a browser, the website starts `SignalR`-stream and load the needed schedule HTML.

How I can get a similar result from .NET?

---

## SOME SUCCESSES

I found that the site uses the `blazor.server.js` script for manipulations with the `SignalR`-stream. There is its source code: [click](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Boot.Server.ts).

### CONNECTION

I tried to rewrite the JS connection code to C# and I had success. JS:

```
...
async function initializeConnection(options: CircuitStartOptions, logger: Logger, circuit: CircuitDescriptor): Promise<HubConnection> {
  const hubProtocol = new MessagePackHubProtocol();
  (hubProtocol as unknown as { name: string }).name = 'blazorpack';

  const connectionBuilder = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('_blazor')
    .withHubProtocol(hubProtocol);

  options.configureSignalR(connectionBuilder);

  const connection = connectionBuilder.build();
...
```

.NET - **BlazorPackHubProtocol.cs** (I couldn't find any other way to change the protocol name, so I created a shell for `MessagePackHubProtocol`):

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace KuzCode.SignalR.Protocols.BlazorPack
{
    public class BlazorPackHubProtocol : IHubProtocol
    {
        private MessagePackHubProtocol _protocol;

        public string Name => "blazorpack"; // if the protocol has another name, connection fails
        public int Version => _protocol.Version;
        public TransferFormat TransferFormat => _protocol.TransferFormat;

        public BlazorPackHubProtocol(IOptions<MessagePackHubProtocolOptions> options)
        {
            _protocol = new(options);
        }

        public BlazorPackHubProtocol() : this(Options.Create(new MessagePackHubProtocolOptions())) { }

        public bool IsVersionSupported(int version) => _protocol.IsVersionSupported(version);

        public bool TryParseMessage(ref ReadOnlySequence<byte> input, IInvocationBinder binder, out HubMessage message)
            => _protocol.TryParseMessage(ref input, binder, out message);

        public void WriteMessage(HubMessage message, IBufferWriter<byte> output)
            => _protocol.WriteMessage(message, output);

        public ReadOnlyMemory<byte> GetMessageBytes(HubMessage message) => _protocol.GetMessageBytes(message);
    }
}
```

.NET - **BlazorPackProtocolDependencyInjectionExtensions.cs** (for easy use in connection builder):

```
using KuzCode.SignalR.Protocols.BlazorPack;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using System;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class BlazorPackProtocolDependencyInjectionExtensions
    {
        public static TBuilder AddBlazorPackProtocol<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder) where TBuilder : ISignalRBuilder
            => builder.AddBlazorPackProtocol(_ => { });

        public static TBuilder AddBlazorPackProtocol<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder, Action<MessagePackHubProtocolOptions> configure)
            where TBuilder : ISignalRBuilder
        {
            builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHubProtocol, BlazorPackHubProtocol>());
            builder.Services.Configure(configure);

            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

.NET - **KhaiClient.cs** (main class with connection):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KuzCode.KhaiApiClient
{
    public class KhaiClient
    {
        private HubConnection _hubConnection;

        public KhaiClient()
        {
            _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("wss://education.khai.edu/_blazor", configuration =>
                {
                    configuration.SkipNegotiation = false;
                    configuration.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;
                })
                .AddBlazorPackProtocol()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                })
                .Build();
        }

        public async Task ConnectAsync() => await _hubConnection.StartAsync();

        public async Task DisconnectAsync() => await _hubConnection.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

.NET - **Program.cs** (for testing):

```
var khaiClient = new KhaiClient();
khaiClient.ConnectAsync().Wait();

while (true) {}
```

**It's working! I had the next log:**

```
...
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport[1]
      Starting transport. Transfer mode: Binary. Url: 'wss://education.khai.edu/_blazor?id=_f5aporohBDfopQF-CExsA'.

...

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[24]
      Using HubProtocol 'blazorpack v1'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[28]
      Sending Hub Handshake.

...

dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[47]
      Receive loop starting.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection[44]
      HubConnection started.
```

## WHAT NEXT?

Now I tried to recreate some requests but had no success.

Select another group request (I selected group `613п`):
[image]

First response:
[image]

---

Source code: https://github.com/iiKuzmychov/KhaiApiClient.

## Update:

I found a [hub implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4e0d4c44f866c6e37b44f3bc002bd30d0591b23c/src/Components/Server/src/ComponentHub.cs) I want, I can copy-paste code, but I don`t know how to initialize it.

Comment: What are you using to navigate the site? How do you "open" the link? Show us some code

Comment: You need to render this page, so actually execute javascript and build the visual tree, like browser does. You can do this with for example Chromium or various wrappers around it (Puppeteer, CefSharp).

Comment: @LeandroBardelli I just create request using HttpClient.GetAsync

Comment: @Evk thanks for the idea, I will try this, but I think this method will take many time and memory

Comment: There is no other way in general case, since you have to execute javascript. However if all you need is this specific page - then you might be able to connect to their signalr endpoint directly without loading any html pages or executing javascript at all.

Comment: @Evk I tried to connect to web server like site using signalr, but I have no success

Comment: Could you share all the code with me? Maybe in a GitHub repo? That would be very kind!

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to create a desktop app with CefSharp browser (or analogue).
Then you can load the site, get generated source and/or execute javascript to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I know Stack Overflow is not for URL redirects but the short answer is "NO", you can't do that with httpClient or WebClient. So... the option is do it with Selenium but the extension of the explanation is a lot more complex in order to satisfy the question.

I will give you the URL for the tutorial that it's work in this case, but you have to take notation that the short answer for your question is basically "NO, YOU CAN NOT". I think the community will think that this is question is too much broad and doesn't have focus in order to get what you get shortly and puntual.

The tutorial for scraping with selenium (there are a lot similar if you find, by keywords: `scrape` `dynamic web` `javascript` `c#`

https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/scraping-dynamic-web-pages/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this solution too slow, I think. I hope it will turn out to connect to server using SignalR, it looks more elegant

Comment: @KuzCode indeed, but you have to know the deep layer of the system that you are trying to scrap, or use some kind of fake proxy to catch the work inside the connections, like gatling

Comment: Site use blazor.server.js for connection manipulations, I found source code and now I try translate js code to .net

Comment: @KuzCode if you get more information and need help please update your question, will be glade to update my answer

Comment: Thank you for your attention and desire to help, I will update my question tomorrow

Comment: I have updated my question)

Comment: @KuzCode for that reply I think is a lot of work try to reverse the MS js for SignalR work in order to get the data. :(

Comment: I will be happy if you help send and get at least one request)

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, it's better to use a browser-based tool for this purpose. Just load the web page, wait until it is loaded, and then access its DOM.

This approach is pretty straightforward and does not require an in-depth investigation of how that page works.

Here is a quick-and-dirty example of examining the page contents based on [DotNetBrowser](https://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser) and its [DevTools.WinForms](https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/DotNetBrowser-Examples/tree/master/csharp/DevTools.WinForms) example (I think it's possible to do that via CefSharp too, however, I haven't tried it yet)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private IBrowser browser1;
    private IBrowser browser2;
    private IEngine engine;

    #region Constructors

    public Form1()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 engine = EngineFactory
                    .Create(new EngineOptions.Builder
                                {
                                    RenderingMode = RenderingMode.HardwareAccelerated,
                                    RemoteDebuggingPort = 9222
                                }
                               .Build());
                 browser1 = engine.CreateBrowser();
                 browser2 = engine.CreateBrowser();
             })
            .ContinueWith(t =>
             {
                 browserView1.InitializeFrom(browser1);
                 browserView2.InitializeFrom(browser2);

                 browser1.Navigation.LoadUrl("https://education.khai.edu/union/schedule/").ContinueWith(t1=>AccessPageData());
                 browser2.Navigation.LoadUrl(browser1.DevTools.RemoteDebuggingUrl);
             }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AccessPageData()
    {
        IElement table = browser1.MainFrame.Document
                                .GetElementsByTagName("table")
                                 .FirstOrDefault(el => el.Attributes["class"].Contains("table"));
        if (table != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<IElement> rows = table.GetElementsByTagName("tr");
            foreach (IElement row in rows)
            {
                IEnumerable<IElement> dataCells = row.GetElementsByTagName("td");
                foreach (IElement cell in dataCells)
                {
                    Debug.Write($"\t{cell.InnerText}");
                }
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Empty);
            }
        }


    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        engine?.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Output:

```
        Понеділок
08:00 - 09:35   405к2 (корпус-2), Правова компетентність (практика), доцент Голубов Артем Євгенович
09:50 - 11:25   426г (головний к.), Геометричне моделювання та графічні інформаційні технології (лекція), доцент Мсаллам Катерина Петрівна
11:55 - 13:30The thread 0x40c8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
249г (головний к.), Геометричне моделювання та графічні інформаційні технології (лаб. практикум), доцент Мсаллам Катерина Петрівна
13:45 - 15:20   338г (головний к.), Хімія (лаб. практикум), старший викладач Середенко Вікторія Валентинівна
247г (головний к.), Геометричне моделювання та графічні інформаційні технології (практика), доцент Мсаллам Катерина Петрівна
    Вівторок
08:00 - 09:35   222с (самолетка), Українські студії (практика), доцент Медведь Олена Вікторівна
09:50 - 11:25   337г (головний к.), Хімія (лекція), доцент Захарченко Микола Іванович
11:55 - 13:30   
404лк (літальний.к), Мовні компетентності (практика), асистент Федотова Олена Михайлівна
13:45 - 15:20   413к2 (корпус-2), Українські студії (практика), доцент Медведь Олена Вікторівна
    Середа
08:00 - 09:35   426г (головний к.), Правова компетентність (лекція), доцент Голубов Артем Євгенович
413г (головний к.), Мовні компетентності (практика), асистент Кудлай Ольга Ігорівна
09:50 - 11:25   225с (самолетка), Вступ до фаху (лекція), професор Федотов Михайло Миколайович

11:55 - 13:30   Фізичне виховання (практика)
13:45 - 15:20   342г (головний к.), Хімія (лаб. практикум), старший викладач Середенко Вікторія Валентинівна
    Четвер
08:00 - 09:35   129к2 (корпус-2), Вступ до фаху (практика), професор Федотов Михайло Миколайович
304м (моторний к.), Українські студії (лекція), доцент Медведь Олена Вікторівна
09:50 - 11:25   206лк (літальний.к), Лінійна алгебра та аналіт. геом. (лекція), доцент Кощавець Петро Тихонович
11:55 - 13:30   415г (головний к.), Мовні компетентності (практика), асистент Федотова Олена Михайлівна
13:45 - 15:20   401лк (літальний.к), Лінійна алгебра та аналіт. геом. (практика), доцент Кощавець Петро Тихонович
    П'ятниця
08:00 - 09:35   412к2 (корпус-2), Правова компетентність (практика), доцент Голубов Артем Євгенович
09:50 - 11:25   343г (головний к.), Мовні компетентності (практика), асистент Кудлай Ольга Ігорівна
11:55 - 13:30   303с (самолетка), Вступ до фаху (лекція), старший викладач Миронова Світлана Юріївна
303с (самолетка), Вступ до фаху (практика), старший викладач Миронова Світлана Юріївна
13:45 - 15:20   Фізичне виховання (практика)
```

As a result, all the data are available as C# strings. You can then simulate some actions on the web page to switch to another schedule and access the DOM of that page again.

Comment: unfortunately, it isn't working for me, I get no schedule text in debug window

Comment: The web page may build its DOM tree asynchronously after the page is loaded completely. There is no particular event you can wait for to handle this case, but you can experiment with adding a small timeout before trying to access the table.

Comment: okay, thanks anyway!